# Replacing the first date instance if a condition is satisfied

Tags: r, dplyr

I have snapshot data in dataframe like this:

```
zz <- "id  created  snap    stage
ALPHA   2012-09-07  2014-01-02  A
ALPHA   2012-09-07  2014-10-01  End
BETA    2012-08-26  2014-01-04  B
BETA    2012-08-26  2014-06-19  C
BETA    2012-08-26  2014-11-21  End
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-01-04  A
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-03-07  B
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-03-28  C
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-03-29  End
DELTA   2014-07-14  2014-07-15  A
DELTA   2014-07-14  2014-09-26  C
DELTA   2014-07-14  2015-02-06  End"
df <- read.table(text=zz, header = T)
```

I need to replace the `snap` date with the `created` date whenever the `created` date is before `2014-01-01`. But I only want to replace the snap date for the first instance of the observation. Although `id`s move through A-B-C-End in order, an `id` doesn't have to start at A.

For example, this is what I'm looking at for an output:

```
id  created snap    stage
ALPHA   2012-09-07  2012-09-07  A
ALPHA   2012-09-07  2014-10-01  End
BETA    2012-08-26  2012-08-26  B
BETA    2012-08-26  2014-06-19  C
BETA    2012-08-26  2014-11-21  End
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-01-04  A
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-03-07  B
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-03-28  C
GAMMA   2014-01-04  2014-03-29  End
DELTA   2014-07-14  2014-07-15  A
DELTA   2014-07-14  2014-09-26  C
DELTA   2014-07-14  2015-02-06  End
```

Notice that `GAMMA` and `DELTA` remain the same, but `ALPHA` in stage `A` has a snap date replaced, as does `BETA` in stage `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr approach - I start with "mutate_each" to make sure both "created" and "snap" are formatted as proper dates. Then we group the data by "id" and finally use "mutate" together with "replace" to make the required changes to the "snap" column (we check where created is before the cutoff date and where the row_number is 1, i.e. first row in that id group):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(as.Date(.)), created, snap) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(snap = replace(snap, which(created < as.Date("2014-01-01") & row_number() == 1), created))

#Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
#Groups: id
#
#      id    created       snap stage
#1  ALPHA 2012-09-07 2012-09-07     A
#2  ALPHA 2012-09-07 2014-10-01   End
#3   BETA 2012-08-26 2012-08-26     B
#4   BETA 2012-08-26 2014-06-19     C
#5   BETA 2012-08-26 2014-11-21   End
#6  GAMMA 2014-01-04 2014-01-04     A
#7  GAMMA 2014-01-04 2014-03-07     B
#8  GAMMA 2014-01-04 2014-03-28     C
#9  GAMMA 2014-01-04 2014-03-29   End
#10 DELTA 2014-07-14 2014-07-15     A
#11 DELTA 2014-07-14 2014-09-26     C
#12 DELTA 2014-07-14 2015-02-06   End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, snap := if (created[1L] < as.Date('2014-01-01')) 
                    c(created[1L], snap[-1L]), by = id]
```

I've assumed `snap` and `created` are date columns. If they're not, you can convert them by doing:

```
cols = c("snap", "created")
df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols=cols]
```

Comment: Did you run this command and get the required output? I got an error. You would certainly need to convert the data to "data.table" e.g. using `setDT` and you shouldn't need to use `mydata$` inside the "[".